# Calculate coordinates based on distances

Tags: matlab, 2d, distance, point

If you have the following:

- 4 points or more in 2D space
- 1 point (included in those "4 or more") constrained to be origin 0,0
- Coordinates of the other points are unknown
- Distances between all points are known

How do you calculate the coordinates of those points? If there are multiple possible answers, I only need one.
Answer should not be specific to only 4 points, need to know how to do it for more points as well.
I added matlab as a tag because this seems like a typical problem to solve in matlab, but it can be in a different language like C#.
Alternatively if you can search for an answer using Wolfram Alpha, I would like to know how you would enter the search query.

Comment: Are they all the same distance apart?

Comment: You can't actually calculate the coordinates of those points just by knowing the distances. One of the reasons is because a rotation does not affect the distances.

Comment: Distances are not the same. As stated in the question I'm interested in only one possible answer if there are multiple possible answers (because of rotation like you say).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be one logic, 
Suppose there is 4 Points in 2D, first origin is fixed at `1(0,0)`, and you know distance of 1 to 2,3,4 and next you fixed any one point again, as I fixed point `2(5,0)`, now as we also know the distance from 2 to 1,3,4 so draw circle on centre `1(0,0)` of distance from all points, and same repeat for point `2(0,5)`also, so interaction of circles of point `1(0,0)` and `2(5,0)` will determine the other points too.

Distance is only for illustrative purpose only, not mathematically correct, its just concept only.

[image]